# Specify name of button via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, button

I've have code to add button via JQuery, It is used to remove row. Button working correctly, just It's without name like `[]`, but should be like `[X]`. It looks like HTML code created as: `<button class="removeRow"></button>` instead of `<button class="removeRow">X</button>`

**JQuery**

```
$.fn.optionTest.defaults = {
    removeLinkOptions: {
        class: 'removeRow',
        href: 'javascript:;'
    }
};

var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<button>", options.removeLinkOptions));
removeRow = $($(removeRow).html());
row.append(label).append(CertNo).append(PlaceofIssue).append(from).append(to).append(removeRow);
```

Where should I apped this `X` to achieve It?

If something unclear - just ask, if needed I can create JS fiddle.

Comment: please provide us Js fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Should be in this line ,when creating `button`:

```
var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<button>", options.removeLinkOptions).text("X"));
```